# how to add the attribute to each tag while retrieving data from xml using XSLT

Tags: xslt

i have xml file that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pointList SYSTEM "point.dtd">
<pointList>
<point unit="mm">
<x>2</x>
<y>3</y>
</point>
<point unit="cm">
<x>9</x>
<y>3</y>
</point>
<point unit="px">
<x>4</x>
<y>7</y>
</point>
</pointList>
```

Using XSLT i transformed it to html file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match = "/pointList">
    <table border = "1"><xsl:apply-templates/></table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match = "/pointList/point">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pointList/point/x">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pointList/point/y">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now my html looks like this:

```
<table border="1">

<tr>

<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>9</td>
<td>3</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>4</td>
<td>7</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

But i have one more thing to do and i'm stuck. i have the unit attribute in point in my xml file. and i have to add the value of unit to each point so it would looks like this : 2mm 3mm
9cm 3 cm
4px 7 px. Can anyone tell me how i should modify my xslt file so that i get what i want? 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="pointList/point/x">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pointList/point/y">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="pointList/point/*">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), ../@unit)"/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. you see my x and y tags are in point tag and i need to add value of point attribute to x and y attributes. does it make sense?

Comment: yup, thanks i got it. but do you know any other way without using concat()? i haven't studied it yet.

Comment: @Gipsy What's so difficult about using concat that you have to *study* it? Anyway, you could also just use a second `<xsl:value-of>`.

Comment: it's not that i don't want to study it :) my question about retrieving attribute is a part of my homework project, so i can't use function we haven't studied in class yet.

Comment: oh, it's just a small, very small part of my homework : ) and i simply ask for help : )

Comment: @Gipsy - since no one seems to have given you an answer to what `concat` does: it merely chains together arguments.  So, in @Tomalak's answer, it squashes together the text within any node that has a `point` parent (and `pointList` grandparent) and the value of the `point` parent's `@unit` attribute.